# Pasting Hex Colors Into OpenOffice

Tags: copy-paste, openoffice-calc, hexadecimal

I'm attempting to paste a very large table of data containing names of colors and their HTML (hex) equivalent into OpenOffice, but it continues to format my colors as weird data types.

For example, "001489" turns into "1489", or "9E5330" turns into "1.79769313486232E+308", or "672E45" turns into "6.72000000000000E+047", etc. Also, values that only contain numbers are aligned to the right, instead of the left like normal text would

How do I make this data paste as plain text, including making them all align left?

**NOTE** this is the table that I'm attempting to paste into OpenOffice http://us.labelpartners.com/pantone_coated_table.html

Comment: You don't want to copy the color formatting as well?

Comment: I'm just trying to paste the text from the color codes exactly as they appear without OpenOffice changing them into numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have LibreOffice instead of OpenOffice but I believe the process should be the same since they are mostly the same program:

1. Copy the table
2. Go to Calc and Use **Edit->Paste Special...** or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
3. You are given the option to paste as *HTML format* or *Unformatted text*. Choose **Unformatted text**
4. You are given another dialog where you can choose the data types for each column:

   [image: Text import dialog]
5. Click on each column and set the **Column type** dropdown to **Text**
6. Click **OK** and the data should be pasted without numbers being converted to scientific notation.

Comment: also you can select range/multiple columns with Shift and Ctrl (+left mouse button or keyboard arrows)